# 3 Monitors Output with Motherboard Build In Graphics

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, motherboard

I am trying to have 3 monitors output from my ASRock H110M-HDV motherboard PC with Windows 7. However, so far I only manage to get 2 monitor output. When I try to expand the desktop to third monitor, the second monitor will turn off.

How can I have 3 monitor output from my system? Thank you.

Comment: You probably can't. Few low-end graphics cards can drive three screens, no matter how many sockets they have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [webpage](https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H110M-HDV/) of your motherboard clearly states:

- Three graphics output options: D-Sub, DVI-D and HDMI**

**Supports up to 2 displays simultaneously.

Answer (score 4):

Your motherboard doesn't have built in graphics card. Your CPU does, though. (I'm being picky)

This motherboard supports 6th and 7th generation Intel CPUs, so your integrated GPU is HD Graphics 5xx series or HD Graphics 6xx series. These GPUs do support 3 monitors, but [two of them have to be connected using DisplayPort](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000025673/graphics-drivers.html).

Your motherboard provides HDMI, DVI and VGA connectors. You can't use all three of them at the same time because GPU in the processor doesn't support this configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Your motherboard cannot support 3 monitors. If you have a dedicated GPU then you can use those ports. But I would guess that you don't have a dedicated GPU and only going with the onboard graphics.

If you really want three monitors then get a dedicated GPU that can support up to three monitors.